# How to build a Windows Phone app with existing BB WebWorks codes

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, blackberry-webworks

I have a BlackBerry application that was built using WebWorks API - HTML5 - Javascript, and I would like to build it for Windows Phone devices, too. I am new to Windows Phone development. How can I build an Windows Phone app with my existing codes? Is there an API like WebWorks? Or do I have to use PhoneGap? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "Phonegap" is the answer. You can use the same code to make windows phone app using Phone gap.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm creating HTML5 elements like audio in my app, and I guess I'll have to re-write my code using PhoneGap API's?

Comment: yes, you have to rewrite it for windows phone using Phonegap's media API.